# Delete multiple site collections with power shell

Tags: powershell

I was looking for the syntax to delete multiple SC's with PS. The SC's are spread out over several different URL paths. I could use SharePoint manager 2010 but as PS is the supported method I'd prefer to do it this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
Remove-SPSite –Identity "sitename" –GradualDelete –Confirm:$False
```

And also check:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607948(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607948%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add multiple URLs within the -Identity param?

Comment: As far as i know, I don't think so it is possible to add multiple URL's. You need that command one by one for each site collection.

Comment: Ok no worries. This is still much faster than using the central admin tool. Thanks for the TechNet link...I'll use that next time.